# VC++ throws linker errors when working with pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I have this situation:

- A C++ *library* project defines a base class `BaseClass`, containing some pure virtual methods
- A C++ *DLL* project defines a derived class `DerivedClass` from `BaseClass` that fully implements such methods
- A C++ console application instantiates `DerivedClass`

Definition of BaseClass:

Header:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual DWORD initialize(void) = 0;
    virtual DWORD terminate(void) = 0;
};
```

Definition of `DerivedClass`:

Header:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    // ...
    DWORD initialize(void);
    DWORD terminate(void);
};
```

cpp:

```
DWORD DerivedClass::initialize()
{
    //...
    return 0;
}

DWORD DerivedClass::terminate()
{
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

What the console application does:

```
DerivedClass c = DerivedClass();
c.initialize();

return 0;
```

While BaseClass and DerivedClass compile fine (so linking configuration should be good), the console application compiles with the following errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned long __thiscall DerivedClass::initialize(void)" (?initialize@DerivedClass@@UAEKXZ) unresolved
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned long __thiscall DerivedClass::terminate(void)" (?terminate@DerivedClass@@UAEKXZ) unresolved
```

Can't understand why, doesn't DerivedClass correctly declare these virtual methods?

EDIT: The `Project Properties -> Linker -> Input` field of the console app is: `$(OutDir)\base_class.lib;$(OutDir)\derived_class.lib;`, so technically it references all the needed libraries.

Comment: Did you include the .cpp file in the compilation?

Comment: Did you link the lib file, which should be created alongside the dll you mentioned, in the console app?

Comment: In which sense? I'm on Visual Studio, are you talking about some parts of the project configuration dialog?

Comment: @alessandro.francesconi As ixSci already mentioned, you need to link to the .lib file that was generated alongside the original .dll (where the base class is located). Typically, you can add input files to the linker via `Project Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input` (if memory serves right).

Comment: The problem is that it's already done this way. The `Input` field of the console app is: `$(OutDir)\base_class.lib;$(OutDir)\derived_class.lib;`

Both of them are correctly found in the path.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx